# DHCP server hardware

Tags: ubuntu, dhcp, hardware

I have a user who needs to set up a DHCP Server for about 8000 users. Can I set it up on regular PC hardware. So far we have not set it up for more than 200-300 users.

Are there anything which I need to worry about in terms of software/hardware or network interfaces or anything else .This would be standard IHC DHCP server on Ubuntu.

Any thoughts appreciated?

Comment: Ask yourself the question how will your user's systems manage if the DHCP server is down - if it being down isn't a problem then perhaps a regular PC might suffice, if it would cause problems use a proper server. As for the actual load, 8000 DHCP requests is nothing, the CPU in a cell phone could handle that ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The load imposed by a DHCP server with that number of clients is pretty minimal, so any reasonably modern computer would suffice.  Bear in mind that you might want to hold on to your DHCP logs for a while, so plan to allocate some disk space to that.

However, you should think carefully about **redundancy**.  If your DHCP server fails, it could be pretty catastrophic from your users' points of view: your 8000 clients will start to drop off the network as their leases expire.  [The IHC DHCP server has support for failover](https://kb.isc.org/article/AA-00502/0/A-Basic-Guide-to-Configuring-DHCP-Failover.html), so you should plan to install a pair of servers, preferably located in physically separate parts of your buildings.